# how to make asp.net v1.1 validation control compatible with IE9

Tags: asp.net

How to make ASP.net v1.1 compatible with IE9? I have tried all the options available in the forums but nothing seems to work. As soon as i am launching the application its Login page appears with no image displayed (image should come), cross mark is coming for the image and after entering username and password the submit button is not working. It means the validation control of v1.1 is not supoorted in IE9. Can anyone give me a fix, I dont want to change code.

Button command is not working and also when the page is loaded its image is not being displayed and a cross mark is coming for the image.

Regards,
Anshul

Comment: Which ASP.NET control's cause trouble?

Comment: Please provide some example for what you talking about, and what is the issue. Some page, some screen shot, some html rendered... something to see where is the issue.

Comment: As far I know any validation work in IE9 .but say your control to guide you.

Comment: Button command is not working and also when the page is loaded its image is not being displayed and a cross mark is coming for the image. Code for button: <input type="button" id="cmdLogin" name="cmdLogin" value="Login" class="clscommand" onclick="fnLogin();

Comment: Code for image: <td align="middle" colspan="3"><img src=".\images\newtopbar.gif" width="980"></td>

Answer (score 0):

I don t know did you try that one but good old days we were using the following config part to render correctly other browser especially FF as the agent string format has changed for IE 9 you can give it a try. Place it under the `System.Web` section and add another case for IE 9. I hope it fix your problem.

```
    <browserCaps>
<!-- GECKO Based Browsers (Netscape 6+, Mozilla/Firebird, ...) //-->
<case match="^Mozilla/5\.0 \([^)]*\) (Gecko/[-\d]+)? (?'type'[^/\d]*)([\d]*)/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+)(?'letters'\w*)).*">
    browser=Gecko
    type=${type}
    frames=true
    tables=true
    cookies=true
    javascript=true
    javaapplets=true
    ecmascriptversion=1.5
    w3cdomversion=1.0
    css1=true
    css2=true
    xml=true
    tagwriter=System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter
    <case match="rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+)(?'letters'\w*))">
        version=${version}
        majorversion=${major}
        minorversion=${minor}
        <case match="^b" with="${letters}">
            beta=true
        </case>
    </case>
</case>
<!-- AppleWebKit Based Browsers (Safari...) //-->
<case match="AppleWebKit/(?'version'(?'major'\d)(?'minor'\d+)(?'letters'\w*))">
    browser=AppleWebKit
    version=${version}
    majorversion=${major}
    minorversion=0.${minor}
    frames=true
    tables=true
    cookies=true
    javascript=true
    javaapplets=true
    ecmascriptversion=1.5
    w3cdomversion=1.0
    css1=true
    css2=true
    xml=true
    tagwriter=System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter
    <case match="AppleWebKit/(?'version'(?'major'\d)(?'minor'\d+)(?'letters'\w*))( \(KHTML, like Gecko\) )?(?'type'[^/\d]*)/.*$">
        type=${type}
    </case>
</case>
<!-- Konqueror //-->
<case match="Konqueror/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+)(?'letters'));\w*(?'platform'[^\)]*)">
    browser=Konqueror
    version=${version}
    majorversion=${major}
    minorversion=${minor}
    platform=${platform}
    type=Konqueror
    frames=true
    tables=true
    cookies=true
    javascript=true
    javaapplets=true
    ecmascriptversion=1.5
    w3cdomversion=1.0
    css1=true
    css2=true
    xml=true
    tagwriter=System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter
</case>
```

Comment: A case for IE is already present in mu config file. Can you please suggest the other method?

Comment: the only thing come to my mind is Client Scripts. under the aspnet_client folder. Be sure you have registered them correctly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=VS.100%29.aspx. And in case they are not supporting the IE9 scripts you can override it and use your own but I really don t remember how use google to find out. But even if scrips it should not effect display of the images just effects validations and submits basically forms.

Comment: Hi Topal,I have registered it correctly, but still the perbolem in persisting. Can anyone help?